# How to start on this Priority Queue homework?

Tags: java

Could someone give me hints on how to solve this problem?

> A store announces a sale campaign whereby any customer who buys two items gets 50% off on the cheaper one. If the customer buys more than two items, he/she must group them into pairs of two to indicate the items that the oer should apply to.
>
> 1. Suppose you want to buy n items in total. Write a method that will give you the best pairing of the items (the one with the minimum price). The method's signature is:
>
>    ```
>    public static LinkedList<ItemPair> minPairing(LinkedList<Item> items).
>    ```
> 2. If you leave it up to the store owner, he/she will try to pair the items in order to obtain the maximum price. Write a method that will help the store owner achieve this. The method's signature is:
>
>    ```
>    public static LinkedList<ItemPair> maxPairing(LinkedList<Item> items).
>    ```
> 3. How much will you gain if you use your method (instead of the shop owner's method) for the following list of item prices: 60 $, 100 $, 400 $, 600 $, 200 $, 80 $.

Using the following classes:

```
public class Item {
    private int id;
    private double price;

    public Item (int id, double price ) {
        this.id = id;
        this. price = price;
    }
    int getId () {
        return id;
    }
    double getPrice () {
        return price;
    }
}
```

and the class :

```
public class ItemPair {
    public Item first;
    public Item second;

    public ItemPair (Item first, Item second ) {
        this. first = first;
        this. second = second;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Edited to add `PriorityQueue` as requested.*

1. For `minPairing()` copy the `items` into a `new PriorityQueue<Item>` with a  `Comparator<Item>` which compares the items prices. Then always pair (`ItemPair`) the top ones from the queue using `.poll()`. Repeat until list ist empty.

   To create the `PriorityQueue` try this:

   ```
   PriorityQueue<Item> pq = new PriorityQueue<Item>(items.size(), new Comparator<Item>() {
           public int compare(Item i1, Item i2) {
               return Float.compare(i1.getPrice(), i2.getPrice());
           });
   for (Item item : items) {
       pq.add(item);
   }
   ```
2. For `maxPairing()` - in my opinion - a `PriorityQueue` doesn't make much sense, as you need to pair the most expensive one with the cheapest one. I would just go with a sorted `List<Item>` here (see [`Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))). Pick the first and the last item from the list and create an `ItemPair`. Then `remove` both from the list. Repeat until list ist empty.
3. compare the sum of the prices of the `ItemPair`s provided by those two methods.

   You may need to implement a `getPrice()` method to `ItemPair`:

   ```
   double getPrice () {
       // assumes that second is cheaper one:
       return first.getPrice() + (second.getPrice() / 2);
   }
   ```

Comment: Edited to add `PriorityQueue` as requested.